# python mutating a list while for loop Error

Tags: python, list, loops

All I want to do is removing any duplicate elements in the list L.C(L) is working, but D(L) shows TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable when I run it. I think there no differences between these two functions. I can not figure out why it comes out with type error:

```
def C(L):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if not(L[i] in l):
            l = l + [L[i]]
    return l
def D(L):
    l = []
    print type(l)
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if not (L[i] in l):
            l = l.append(L[i])
    return l
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change a list to `set` to make it unique,and then back to `list` if you want actually a `list`.

Comment: they are not changing the list during the loop

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
l = l + [L[i]]
```

is not equivalent to this:

```
l = l.append(L[i])
```

The line above assigns to `l` the value return value of calling the `append` function, which is `None`.

You can just use instead:

```
l.append(L[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

`l = l.append(L[i])` this results in `l` being Non, because append works in place. So just change `l = l.append(L[i])` into `l.append(L[i])`. This should help.